# chrome load trace.html with error

Tags: android, google-chrome, systrace

I have generated a `trace.html` file with `android studio`,but when i loaded that file with chrome browser,i got the error:

```
Error:Could not find an importer for the provided eventData
```

I have tried many solutions but failed. Can anyone give me some advice?

thanks in advance.

[image]

It seems that my trace.html is incomplete，i don't know why.
[image]